# Laravel 7 HTTP client attach multiple files

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to make POST to a rest API where I need to send multiple files from a user input form. I have managed to get it to work with a single file, but when there are multiple files sent as an array ($file[]), I can't see anything in the laravel docs to show how this can be done.

```
$response = 'API_URL';
        $response = Http::withToken(ENV('API_KEY'))
        ->attach('file', fopen($request->file, 'r'))
        ->post($url, [
           'uuid' => $request->uuid,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
->attach('file[0]', fopen($request->file[0], 'r'))
->attach('file[1]', fopen($request->file[1], 'r'))
```

if your `$files` is an array of files that wants to send, you can do like below:

```
$response = Http::withToken(ENV('API_KEY'));

foreach ($files as $k => $file) {
  $response = $response->attach('file['.$k.']', $file);
}

$response = $response->post($url, [
  'uuid' => $request->uuid,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Attach multiple files if the file name also unknown, together with request data in one request, if request has file or does not have file. with authorization header

```php
if ($method == 'POST') {
    // Attached multiple file with the request data
    $response = Http::withHeaders($headers);
    if($request->files) {
        foreach ($request->files as $key=> $file) {
            if ($request->hasFile($key)) {
                // get Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instance
                $image = $request->file($key);
                $fileName = $request->file($key)->getClientOriginalName();
                $response = $response->attach($key, $image->get(),$fileName);
            }
        }
        $response = $response->post($this->$requestUrl, $request->all());
    } else {
        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($this->webApiBaseUri, $request->all());
    }
}
```